"When doubling the width and length of the MOSFET in a ring oscillator, the output frequency decreases. What could be the cause?"
"After conducting simulations, I found that doubling both the width and length of the PMOS (210n, 45n) and NMOS (120n, 45n) transistors resulted in a decrease in the output frequency. It's commonly known that increasing the length leads to slower operation, while increasing the width enhances speed. Hence, I expected these effects to offset each other. Why then did the output frequency decrease? Is the impact of length more significant? If so, why?



The channel resistance isn't the only factor in play here. What about capacitance?
